# Async FileDownloader that compare files with hash codes from a list

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to make a launcher for my game. The launcher should make a check for the files when I click on the "Play" button.

I want to check the hash codes (for example the patch files) that are already installed and the patch files on my server. The files that I want to check should be in a .txt file list.

When the code is not a match with the files on the server, I want to overwrite the local files.

After downloading the file the next one should start until all files are downloaded. I want to show progress with a ProgressBar.

I tested that with only one file that is hard coded. With more files I didn't find a solution.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim URL As String = "http://213.196.154.200/downloads/WOTLK/WOTLK/Data/patch-3.MPQ"
        Application.DoEvents()
        hhtpclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(URL), Pfad + "/data/patch-3.mpq", Stopwatch.StartNew)
        Application.DoEvents()
        Label2.Visible = True
        Label3.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Label5.Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Download fehlgeschlagen!" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub hhtpclient_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles hhtpclient.DownloadFileCompleted
    If Abbort = "0" Then
        Dim customMsgbox1 = New Form2("Download erfolgreich!")
        customMsgbox1.btnCustomNo.Visible = False
        customMsgbox1.btnCustomYes.Location = New Point(179, 229)
        customMsgbox1.ShowDialog()
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Abbort = "0"
        PictureBox8.Visible = False
    Else
        Dim customMsgbox2 = New Form2("Download abgebrochen!")
        customMsgbox2.btnCustomNo.Visible = False
        customMsgbox2.btnCustomYes.Location = New Point(179, 229)
        customMsgbox2.ShowDialog()
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Abbort = "0"
    End If
    Button2.Visible = False
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Label5.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub hhtpclient_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles hhtpclient.DownloadProgressChanged
    Dim SW As Stopwatch
    SW = Stopwatch.StartNew
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    Dim totalbytes As Double = e.TotalBytesToReceive
    Dim bytes As Double = e.BytesReceived
    If totalbytes >= "1000000000" Then
        Label2.Text = Math.Round(bytes / 1024000000.0, 2) & " / " & Math.Round(totalbytes / 1024000000.0, 2) & " GB"
    ElseIf totalbytes >= "1000000" Then
        Label2.Text = Math.Round(bytes / 1024000.0, 2) & " / " & Math.Round(totalbytes / 1024000.0, 2) & " MB"
    End If

    If bytes >= "1000000" Then
        Label3.Text = (e.BytesReceived / 1024000.0 / (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#)).ToString("0.0") & " MB/s"
    ElseIf bytes >= "1000" Then
        Label3.Text = (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#)).ToString("0.0") & " KB/s"
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried this code. The Files will download but I don't how to add a ProgressBar and the application freeze when the files downloading:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '===Downloadvorgang===
    Dim Einl() As String = Split(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("D:/Test.txt"), vbNewLine)
    For i As Long = 0 To UBound(Einl)
        Dim l() As String = Split(Einl(i), ";")
        Dim url As String = l(0)
        Dim dateiname As String = l(1)
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(url, "D:/" & dateiname, "", "", False, 100000, True)
    Next
    MsgBox("Die Dateien wurden erfolgreich heruntergeladen!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Download beendet")
    '===Downloadvorgang Ende====
End Sub
```

Comment: Which part of the code is the root of your issue? And did you receive any error messages for the solution(s) that you tried? If so, please list them.

Comment: ther's no issuses. The code is for a simple file. But i need a code to download more that one file which are listed in a .txt file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What part of the ProgressBar are you having trouble with?  You need to set the Maximum value, the Step value and then inside your loop, call `pb.PerformStep()`  Keep GUI controls out of background threads otherwise.

Comment: The issue is that the application freeze. So the progressBar don't fill